# Hibernate: object won't save into the database

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, struts2

I am working a web application that accepts a user information once the user has submit the form  the controller will populate the values and pass it to the service layer.
 The Service Layer will then call the DAO that adds it to the database, but upon calling save, it only showed the query  but it did not save the user into the database.

Here's a snippet of my `ServiceLayer`

```java
public void addUser(User user){
    userDao.save(user);
}
```

And this is my user dao

```java
@Override
    public void save(User type) {
        sess().save(type);
    }
```

On my console this showed up.

```java
Hibernate: insert into USERS (USERNAME) values (?)
```

but it did not save into the database why?

I am using strut2-spring-plugin and hibernate.

Comment: Is the service @Transactional?

Comment: Oh shoot! I forgot about that!!

Comment: No commit ... how will it save into db.. lol

Comment: @user962206 ok.. but whats the purpose of posting the question then... just remove it.. or close it.. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my error! before duffymo commented it. I do not have @Transactional in my service layer that's why the changes won't save into the databas

```
@Transactional
public class MyService(){

  //Other methods
}
```